# Displaying image in Iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I want to display an image within an iframe on my webpage. However, the problem is that I can't get it to expand to 100% of its size.

What I want to do is the following.

- Have an iframe on my webpage.
- Call an image within the iframe.
- Make the image expand to full-size and as a reaction, the iframe allows me to scroll.
- Not have any scroll bars on my webpage

Currently, here's the code I have:

```
echo"<iframe name='graph' id='graph' src=$image style='position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:100%;width:100%'></iframe>";
```

What this does is that, it makes the iframe come on top of my webpage and still doesn't expand to 100%. If i remove the position:absolute instead:

```
echo"<iframe name='graph' id='graph' src=$image style='top:0px; left:0px; height:100%;width:100%'></iframe>";
```

I end up getting it to expand in width to 100%, but in terms of height, it is just 3 pixels high and there is a scrollbar to scroll to the bottom.

I scoured the web looking for a fix, but nothing I tried works. Some mentioned changing CSS as well, but to no avail ...

**EDIT**

Another problem I face is that the image is *zoomed out* in Firefox. I need to click on the image within the iframe to expand it to its full size. It shows up correctly in Chrome and IE though. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Why are you placing the images in iframes in the first place? Doing so takes them outside the scope of your CSS rules or JavaScript on your page, severely limiting your control of your own page.

Comment: Dan, I don't want my large image to introduce scroll bars to my page. Not the best way of doing it maybe, I know ...

Comment: Then put them inside a div with a fixed maximum size, set its overflow property so it gets the scrollbars instead of your page, and use JavaScript to resize the image after it loads to fit inside the div and eliminate the scrollbars. Putting the image in an iframe takes away your ability to do such things.

Answer (score 7):

use below code to to display image.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%"
   src="../images/eightball.gif" name="imgbox" id="imgbox">
   <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe><br />


<a href="../images/redball.gif" target="imgbox">Red Ball</a><br />
<a href="../images/floatingball.gif" target="imgbox">Floating Ball</a><br />
<a href="../images/eightball.gif" target="imgbox">Eight Ball</a>
```

Comment: both the attributes 'frameborder' and 'scrolling' are obsolete as of HTML5, leaving CSS as an alternative

Answer (score 2):

You can use some JavaScript to detect the size of the iframe contents and resize the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your main page's CSS:

```
body, html {
   height:100%   
}
```

Comment: It may depend on the rest of your HTML.

Comment: This won't work because he is embedding the image directly, putting it outside the context of the current document.

Answer (score 0):

The container (the enclosing div, if you don't have a container you should create one,) seems to be what is limiting the height of the iframe. Try making the height of the container 100%.

Comment: The iframe is within a table. And the table does have an attribute of height="100%".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are directly embedding an image resource.

This is never going to work the way you want. The image is always going to be original size.

You need to set the `src` property of the iframe to a separate HTML file with a `body` of its own, wrapping around the image. *Then* you can give it 100% width and/or height inside the body using CSS.

Comment: Hmm, rather than creating another page just to display the image. Is there an alternative that I could look into?

All, I really want to do is keep my existing page scroll-free and just be able to scroll my image ...

Comment: @12345 why not use a `div` with `overflow: auto`?

Comment: @FatherStorm well, then show me how you auto-resize that image to the iframe's width?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have access to the image locally AND you can use the php GD functions...

```
$img_rsrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image);
// or imagecreatefrompng, imagecreatefromgif, etc, depending on the type of your image
$height = imagesy($img_rsrc);
$width = imagesx($img_rsrc);
imagedestroy($img_rsrc);
```

Then set the size of your iframe in pixels based on the height and width. You may have to add a bit to the height and width to account for margins.

Comment: Aah ... I thought it worked. Unfortunately it didn't Mike. If the image is large enough, it does add scrolls to my entire page and not just the iframe ...

Comment: Another problem I face is that the image is zoomed out in Firefox. I need to click on the image within the iframe to expand it to its full size. It shows up correctly in Chrome and IE though. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: This is Firefox functionality, because the iframe is too small to show the whole picture. I don't know of a way to suppress this. As for the previous comment, I think you should look into a JavaScript solution.